# Error When Trying to Compile Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:763:14)
Velibors-MacBook-Pro:sage2 vel$
```

Not sure what the problem is, tried googling but none of the suggestions worked.

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: i am just running "gulp" command this is for a mamp wordpress website if that helps..

Comment: its something to do with the images folder
[18:05:39] Starting 'images'...
[18:05:39] Finished 'fonts' after 99 ms
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:763:14)
Velibors-MacBook-Pro:gulp3 vel$

Comment: I don't expect you still remember how you solved this problem?

Comment: Might clarify and help to track the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35641655/1064325