# Node.js - events.js:154 throw err write EPIPE; Program Crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, epipe

Trying to run my Node.js program, which has worked for a long time, and now it is suddenly... not. I'm trying to figure out the problem, and I figured it would be helpful if I posted here to try to track it down. Here's the log output:

```
events.js:154
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:767:14)
```

Quite frankly I have no clue why it's throwing an EPIPE error, I've checked that there's nothing running that could interfere and it's running in the exact same shell as it has before. If there's anything I should add let me know.

Comment: Related to https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11153?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html)

> `EPIPE`: A write on a pipe, socket, or FIFO for which there is no process to read the data. Commonly encountered at the `net` and `http` layers, indicative that the remote side of the stream being written to has been closed.

The steam maybe a `pipe` or `socket` when the other end has terminated the connection. It's a run-time error; there is nothing you can do but close your end as well.

Please check if there is one *big file written* or long *http package request* in your program.

With the following code could make your program exit successfully in this case:

```
process.stdout.on('error', function( err ) {
    if (err.code == "EPIPE") {
        process.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Basically the issue (sorry for taking so long to answer but I haven't checked my SO account for a while) was that the file did not have the proper permissions to be accessed by my user account.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was with the number of inotify watchers as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly)

And here is the [original listen documentation](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```